# why is there an Object Variable or With-block variable missing?

Tags: excel, vba

why is there an

> Object variable or With-bock variable missing

[image: In the Picture is the Problem (in German) and the Code]

I have already googled if I could find anything in the Internet but I didn't

```
Sub One_Find()
    Dim FieldRange As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    FieldRange = Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address

    Do
        FieldRange = Cells.FindNext(FieldRange)
    Loop While FieldRange.Address <> FirstAddress

    FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) then [edit] and improve your question: Add your code formatted as code block and also tell in which line you get the error.

Comment: use `Set FieldRange =........` instead of `FieldRange =. `

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yeah I excidentlly deleted it I wanted the picture and the Code but thanks for hinting at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `FieldRange` is of type `Range` and therefore it is an object, and objects need to use `Set`
2. After using the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) you must test if it was successful by testing it for `Nothing`

So you end up with …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub One_Find()
    Dim FieldRange As Range
    Set FieldRange = Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If FieldRange Is Nothing
        MsgBox "Find failed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address

    Do
        FieldRange = Cells.FindNext(FieldRange)
    Loop While FieldRange.Address <> FirstAddress

    FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Some general rules:

1. Make sure that your code includes the workbook & the worksheet you want to use. This could be achieved using a `With Statement`

   ```
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   End With
   ```
2. Avoid `ActiveCell` and refer to cell using cell address.
3. Before you use `FieldRange` make sure that you check if it is `Nothing` or not.

   ```
   If FieldRange Is Nothing Then
       Debug.Print "Value was not found."
   Else
       Debug.Print "Value found in :" & FieldRange.Address
   End If
   ```
4. A `Do … While` structure

   ```
   Do While i < 5
       i = i + 1
       MsgBox "The value of i is : " & i
   Loop
   ```